# What is the authenticity of these ahadith prohibiting the duff?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

> Hadhrat Ali (radhiyallahu anhu) said: "Rasulullah (sallallahu alayhi wasallam) prohibited beating of the duff (drum) and the sound of the flute." (Nailul Autaar)
>
> Hadhrat Ali (radhiyallahu anhu) narrated: "Rasulullah (sallallahu alayhi wasallam) forbade beating the duff, playing the harp and blowing the flute." (Kanzul Ummaal)

Comment: @UmH Aalamoalaikum. Would you be able to help me with this question? JazakAllah.

Answer (score -1):

[Musical drums have been declared haraam unanimously by all authorities from the very age of the Sahaabah.](https://www.muftisays.com/blog/abu+mohammed/362_25-06-2010/40-hadith-on-music.html)

Comment: I’m aware of the source of these narratives. However, this website contains many daif Hadith a which is why I am asking for authenticity.